# Issue referencing instance of object in jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, I'm new to object-oriented JS but fairly experienced with JS and jQuery.

I'm having an issue which makes no sense and is better explained in code, see below:

```
var $table = $("tbody#peopleContainer"); // hypothetical table to which we will append rows for each person object

var Person = function( name ) { //nothing special here
    this.name = name;
    this.nickname = "";
}
Person.prototype = {
    create: function() {
        $tr = $table.append("<tr></tr>"); //create a blank row

        this.$name = $('<td>'+this.name+'</td>').appendTo( $tr );
        this.$nickname = $('<td><input type="text"></td>').appendTo( $tr );

        $table.append( this.$td ).append( this.$nickname ); 

        self = this;
        this.$name.on("click", $.proxy(self.logName, self)); // logs the name of the person's row you clicked
        $("input", this.$nickname).change(function() { // Should log the nickname you typed as well as the person's name whose nickname you changed
            self.nickname = $(this).val();
            $.proxy(self.logNameAndNickname, self)();  // Problem! Logs the nickname you typed in, but ALWAYS logs the last instantiated person's name
        })
    },
    logName: function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    },
    logNameAndNickname: function() {
        console.log(this.name, this.nickname); // for some reason this.name returns the last instantiated person's name (Person #0).
    }
}

// create 100 people and append to table
x = 100;
while ( x-- > 0 ) {
    person = new Person("Person #"+x);
    person.create();
}
```

for some reason, `logName()` logs the right person's name, but `logNameAndNickname()` always logs the last instantiated person's name, although it logs the correct nickname. It's as if `this` is referencing 2 separate objects in the same scope.

So my question is -  What's going on here?

Followup question: Is this the right way of using jQuery events with objects? I'm new to object oriented JS so please let me know if there's a more appropriate way to accomplish this same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is an unintentionally global variable, which will be overwritten by each constructor and then hold the last instance after the while loop. You need to make it local to the constructor scope.

Also, if you use `$.proxy` you do *not* need to use `self`, and if you use `self` you do *not* need to use `$.proxy`.

```
this.$name.on("click", $.proxy(this.logName, this));
/* is equivalent to 
var self = this;
this.$name.on("click", function() {
    self.logName()
}); */
```

```
var self = this;
this.$nickname.find("input").change(function() {
    self.nickname = $(this).val();
    self.logNameAndNickname();
});
/* or
this.$nickname.find("input").change($.proxy(function(e) {
    this.nickname = e.target.value;
    this.logNameAndNickname();
}, this)); */
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

1) `self` is a global variable (defined w/o the `var` keyword) and it gets "overwritten" every time a Person is created.

2) Then you proxy both `logName` and `logNameAndNickname` which replaces the this reference in those functions to `self` which will always refer to the *last* Person created.

Comment: Thank you. Can you show how you would rewrite this to work properly?

Comment: Well, can't really figure what exactly the code is meant to do and why you need to proxy those functions, but to fix the this reference, just add the `var` keyword, e.g. `var self = this` I also recommend not using `self` for variable name as Gecko based browsers use it as a reference to the `window` object which may lead to problems.